# Греется процессор

Tags: cpu

Всем привет.
Вопрос вот в чем, ноут lenovo e120, делал чистку от пыли, проц термопастой смазал, постоянно процессор загружен 80-90%, температура 67-80 градусов, даже если открыт один word. Подскажите, где копать, как решить проблему?

Comment: посмотрите каким процессом или процессами загружен сам процессор

Comment: А это в самом деле не нормально?  В [первой же ссылке](http://antonkozlov.ru/otvety-na-voprosy/kakaya-dolzhna-byt-temperatura-processora-2.html), выданной гуглом на запрос `нормальная температура процессора в ноутбуке` утверждают, что `в основном рабочая температура процессора при нагрузке варьируется в пределах от 60 до 80 градусов.`

Comment: Сколько лет ноутбуку? Если он старый, то это, увы, нормальная ситуация: микросхемы изготавливаются по очень тонким микронным технологиям, расстояния между слоями очень малы, довольно быстро они начинают "течь", как результат, со временем выделяется всё больше тепла, а производительность падает.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь сложно сказать наверняка, в чем кроется проблема. Как правило, подобные вопросы решаются при личном осмотре пациента. Однако, могу предположить следующее:

- Проблема непосредственно с системой. Проведите диагностику, в частности - проверьте на вирусы. Постоянно высокая загрузка процессора - это ненормально.
- Проблема с самим процессором. Маловероятно. Я не встречал такого, чтобы от каких-либо внешних факторов процессор постоянно работал практически в полную мощность.

Comment: На вирусы проверял, все хорошо, я думал что может винда жрьот, поставил линукс, ситуация не поменялась. Даже если только переустановил систему, поставил один браузер, захожу в инет и началось проц греется и загрузка большая.

Comment: @Vadym После "На вирусы проверял" я бы написал "__вроде бы__ все хорошо". И, все-таки, какой процесс занимает ресурсы процессора?